# Transform data table

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transform

I have a data set that looks like this:

[image]

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Category': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B'], 'SubCategory': ['A01', 'A02', 'A02', 'B01', 'B01', 'B02', 'B03'], 'SubSubCategory': ['AA01', 'AA02', 'AA03', 'BB01', 'BB02', 'BB03', 'BB04'], 'ProductID': [1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005, 1006, 1007]})

[Out]:

  Category SubCategory SubSubCategory  ProductID
0        A         A01           AA01       1001
1        A         A02           AA02       1002
2        A         A02           AA03       1003
3        B         B01           BB01       1004
4        B         B01           BB02       1005
5        B         B02           BB03       1006
6        B         B03           BB04       1007
```

I want to transform the data to look like this:

[image]

Comment: provide reproducible data and explain in detail the logic

Comment: Also, please format the tables as described [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/277716/how-can-i-create-a-table-in-a-post), instead of posting images.

Comment: Although I love a puzzle, I can't figure out where these values of the column `Value` are coming from...

Comment: @guin0x `random.randint` obviously ;)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Where do the values from the column `Value` come from?